# Free Linux software to stitch photos together (Like photo-stitch from Canon for windows)

Tags: linux, photos

Any one know of any *Free Linux* software to stitch photos together (Like photo-stitch from Canon for windows)

Answer (score 4):

[Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) is available at Sourceforge and also as a debian package in Ubuntu.

> Hugin has now reached stable state: the software is recommended for general use.

And, I second that -- its now an excellent tool (after many iterations).